# Search result property count in Lucene

Tags: lucene, search-engine

I'm using Lucene.Net in my web site to search Contacts. Each contact contains properties like gender, age and city. I'm using paging and receiving 10 results each time.

I need to add a tool bar to narrow the results by the properties, for example:

```
Gender: Male (154), Female (103)

Age: 0-16 (34), 17-24 (86), 25-34 (117)
```

Is there an easy way to get this information during the search?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia:

[Faceted search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faceted_search), also called faceted navigation or faceted browsing, is a technique for accessing information **organized according to a faceted classification system**, **allowing users to explore a collection of information by applying multiple filters.**

A standard example of Faceted Search is LinkedIn. When you search for "software developer", in addition to the results, you also get IBM (2002 people), Amazon (1500), etc.. type of browsing capability, which is very similar to your requirement.

Fortunately, Lucene offers this feature. The following are the tutorials on Faceted Search using Lucene.

[Faceted Search lucene.net](https://cwiki.apache.org/LUCENENET/simple-faceted-search.html)

[Official Apache Lucene Faceted Search](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_2/api/all/org/apache/lucene/facet/doc-files/userguide.html)

[Another Lucene Faceted Search tutorial](http://shaierera.blogspot.com/2012/11/lucene-facets-part-1.html)